# Why macro defined within a C function is not documented by Doxygen?

Tags: c, doxygen

I have the following code in a file named foo.c.

```
/** @file */
#include <stdio.h>

/** Prints hello */
#define hello() printf("hello, ")

int main()
{
    /** Prints world */
    #define world() printf("world\n")
    hello();
    world();
}
```

I have a file named Doxyfile in the same directory.

```
PROJECT_NAME = Foo
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF = YES
```

When I run the `doxyfile` command, I get a documentation that looks like this.

[image: Doxygen output]

Why is there no documentation generated for the `world()` macro? How can I ensure that documentation is generated for the `world()` macro too without bringing it out of the function `main()`?

Comment: Since macros have global scope, why can't you define `world()` just before the definition of `main()`?

Comment: Did you try moving the #define and comment to column 1 ?

Comment: Possible that Doxygen is using archaic rules for macro alignment (or a parser with similarly archaic or incorrectly defined rules). Pre-ANSI C, [macros were not allowed to have whitespace between the beginning of the line and the `#`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/cpp_48.html).

Comment: Moving the `#define` and its comment to column 1 did not help.

Comment: when a tool. like the compiler or the linker or some documentation tool like doxygen indicates the code has a problem, rather than fighting the tool, fix the problem.  in this case, move the #define statement to before the signature for the main() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros/variables/etc inside functions bodies are [outside the scope of Doxygen](https://sourceforge.net/p/doxygen/mailman/message/9030441/) and thus no documentation is generated for them at this time.